# How can I send multiple Props to Component in React with Material-UI Props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-props

I have react component with MUI DrawerProps:

`export default function Navigator(props: DrawerProps)`

But i need two more props, e.g.

```
interface Props {
  items: string;
  onItemClick: (nr: number) => void;
}
```

So if i do smth like this:

`export default function Navigator(props: DrawerProps, props2: Props)`

I cant send my Props to component like this:

```
<Navigator
              PaperProps={{ style: { width: drawerWidth } }}
              variant="temporary"
              open={mobileOpen}
              onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
              onItemClick={handleSelectedId} //here problems
              items={selectedId.toString()}  //here problems
            />
```

Now i make this:

```
interface Props extends DrawerProps {
  items: string;
  onItemClick: (nr: number) => void;
}
```

And its working but i have warning in console:

```
*react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Unknown event handler property `onItemClick`. It will be ignored.*
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2866:66 .........
```

Do you have any idea how can I pass it??
Thank You. Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
export default functionNavigator(props: DrawerProps & Props)
```

makes `props` an extension of `DrawerProps`.
Now, `items` and `onItemClick` are expected in the `props` you call `Navigator` with.